# ParseFile: cannot call then in save function

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, parse-platform, sails.js

I try to save an image using ParseFile in js sdk and I retrieve this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
    at Object.Parse.File.save (/PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:4281:43)
    at null.<anonymous> (/PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:5984:21)
```

here is my ejs code:

```
<form class="basic-grey" action="/confirm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id="picture" name="picture" type="file" class="button"</input>
</form>
```

controller:

```
  confirm: function (req, res) {
    var file = new Parse.File(req.files.picture.name, req.files.picture);

    file.save().then(function(file) {
        console.log('FILE: '+ file);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('ERROR: '+ error.message);
    });
  }),
```

req.files.picture is defined, I don't understand why save does not work.

Could you help me ?

Comment: `Parse.File` requires the second parameter as the file data where as you are sending a JSON object. By the way, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: but req.files.image is a data not a JSON object isn't it ? do I have to read it using fs, to retrieve that data object ? I'm trying to upload image file

Comment: imo issue is not with 'then' function at all. Its with what objects/fields are in the call to 'save'

Comment: http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.File.html#save

Comment: @RobertRowntree thx, I did read the doc, parse save function takes a data as second argument, is req.files.picture a data file ?

Comment: They should have file uploads in the js docs.

Comment: Already go through it and it did not help me to fix the issue

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To save uploaded file to a specific location use the following

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(req.files.picture.path, function (err, data) {
   fs.writeFile('pathYouWantToSaveFile', data, function(err, result){
      // done
      // delete the file from temp location
      fs.unlink(req.files.picture.path);
   });
});
```

NB: `req.file.picture.path` is the temporary location where the file is uploaded.

to make use `Parse.File` you can try the following (not tested though).

```
var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile(req.files.picture.path, function (err, data) {
       var file = new Parse.File('pathYouWantToSaveFile', data);
       file.save().then(function(file) {
          console.log('FILE: '+ file);
       }, function(error) {
          console.log('ERROR: '+ error.message);
       });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your response but the second solution does not work :s